# Docker for Windows - Volumes data lost after PC restart

Tags: docker

I'm working with Docker for Windows (19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d), with WSL2. I've been creating containers and mounting volumes for them (`/data/some_mariadb:var/lib/mysql`, `/volumes/some_fluentd:fluentd/log`, etc.).
However after restarting my PC, all the data is lost. I have an older Docker instance (not using WSL2) running on another PC, and it's volume mounts are working fine. Could this be an issue with WSL2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this. Instead of mounting to a simple directory like `/volumes/<name>`, I've noticed that docker by default(if no volume mounts are specified) mounts to a directory like this: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/a43027e1f06.../_data` and the data is always preserved after machine restart.

So I've made a mount like this `/var/lib/docker/volumes/some_fluentd:fluentd/log` and it's working. The data is preserved after machine restart.